# Using AutoHotKey for splitting the screen into panes/windows

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use **AutoHotKey** ***to split the desktop screen in 6 equally-sized panes/windows*** to ease my code reviewing activity.

I can't find any script to split it into six equal parts but I found to split the screen into 2-4 parts here: [Link To The Script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/37116-split-screen/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SetWinDelay -1

^1:: Area1()
^2:: Area2()
^3:: Area3()
^4:: Area4()
^5:: Area5()
^6:: Area6()

^7::
i := "" ; number of windows
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{   
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If !(exStyle & 0x100)
        continue
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If (title = "")
        continue
    i++
    WinActivate, ahk_id %this_ID%
        Area%i%()
}
return

; Top_Left
Area1(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , 0, 0,(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}

; Top_Middle
Area2(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth/3), 0,(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}

; Top_Right
Area3(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , (2*A_ScreenWidth/3), 0,(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}

; Bottom_Left
Area4(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , 0, (A_ScreenHeight/2),(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}

; Bottom_Middle
Area5(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth/3), (A_ScreenHeight/2),(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}

; Bottom_Right
Area6(){
    WinRestore, A   
    WinMove, A, , (2*A_ScreenWidth/3), (A_ScreenHeight/2),(A_ScreenWidth/3),(A_ScreenHeight/2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the script! Now, I'm more productive.